# Search inside array contain multiple arrays, how?

Tags: php, arrays

What I am doing wrong?
This code always return nothing.
How can search in multiple arrays ?

```
<?php

    $a = array("x", "c");
    $b  = array("v", "b");
    $c = array("n", "m");

    $arrayglobal  = array($a, $b, $c);

    if (array_walk_recursive($arrayglobal,"b")) 
         {
         print  "found";
         }

    else {
         print  "nothing";
         }

?>
```

Comment: What code did you use?

Comment: array_walk_recursive() might help you.

Comment: Sorry I correct the code and add PHP,
Please can update my code, im not lazy just new with php.

Comment: A variable name cannot start with a number, have you tried `array_walk_recursive()` as mentioned by C Miller?

Comment: I corrected variable names now.
I not really understand how use array_walk_recursive()

Comment: array_walk_recursive not work i update the code and that also not work

Comment: array_walk_recursive takes two arguments. One is the array you want to traverse and the other is the name of a function you want to run on each element. So you can't just swap it out with your old code. You would need to write the function that checks to see if the value == 'b' and then put the name of that function as your second argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [array_merge()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp) for combine array then code like given below.

```
<?php 
    $a = array("x", "c");
    $b = array("v", "b");
    $c = array("n", "m");

    $arrayglobal  = array_merge($a, $b, $c);

    if(in_array("b",$arrayglobal)){
        print  "found";
    }
    else{
        print  "nothing";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a two-dimensional array, you can just loop then check if `in_array()`

```
$search = 'b';
$result = 'nothing';

foreach ($arrayglobal as $array) {
    if (in_array($search, $array)) {
        $result = 'found';
        break;
    }
}

print $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow and php world . In our php world we have same rules. Rules like:

1. A variable starts with the $ sign, followed by the name of the variable
2. A variable name must start with a letter or the underscore character
3. A variable name cannot start with a number
4. A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (A-z, 0-9, and _ )
5. Variable names are case-sensitive ($var and $VAR are two different variables)

Our world is very strict with this rule .... xD

```
$a = array("x", "c");// A variable name must start with a letter or the underscore character
$b  = array("v", "b");
$c = array("n", "m");

$f=1;
$arrayglobal  = array($a, $b, $c);

foreach ($arrayglobal as $array) {
if (in_array("b", $array)) {
    $f=0;
     echo "found";
    break;
 }
}
if($f == 1){
         echo "nothing";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_walk_recursive()` with target arrays as first parameter & anonymous function as a 2nd parameter which process each arrays within this anonymous function.

You could use it like this :

```
<?php

$_1 = array("x", "c");
$_2  = array("v", "b");
$_3 = array("n", "m");

$arrayglobal  = array($_1, $_2, $_3);


array_walk_recursive($arrayglobal, function ($item)
{
    echo $item == "b" ? "found\n" : "nothing\n";
});

?>
```